# How to find the encryption method of url parameters on the front end

Tags: html

For example, a website like this：https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BbL2PZ5394，How do I find his encryption function method and then decrypt it into plaintext data?

I tried searching for URL parameter decryption, SSL decryption, URL parameter encryption methods, etc. on major video websites, but I couldn't find the answer I wanted.I hope someone can tell me how to find the parameter encryption method function and decryption of the URL

Comment: Looking at the video briefly, I think your question is about "serialization". This individual is using `JSON.stringify()` to turn a JavaScript object into a string, and turning it back into a JavaScript object by using `JSON.parse()`. The individual is also using "URL encoding" to make sure the string is sent with all the special characters intact in the URL, via something like `encodeURIComponent()`, which is the reason for the % symbol appearing so many times.

Comment: You don't. They can us any method they want, and it probably relies on a random cryptographic secret.